Greetings, I get ERROR 500 when trying to access my website I have hosted via IIS Manager
Greetings and good day,
I have a ASP.NET 8.0 Razor project that I have created in VS22. I had finished the project and was ready to publish it via IIS.
I followed the most of the basic instruction to host it via 'Sites' -> 'Add Website' -> Setting the 'Site name' -> Went and created separate folder where I added my files from my project
(Done so by right-clicking -> Publish -> Going to the project folder where is published -> Checking the web.config file if everything is fine)
-> After adding the files that I published I configured it to https -> All Unassigned in the 'IP address -> Using a free port -> clicked OK
Then from the Browse Website on the right I clicked 'Browse *:port (https) and when I opened the website this error came up(one in the snippet):
Afterwards I decided that it is probably a web.config error as via debugging there didnt seem to be any issues. My web.config looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Partnership_Project_Internal.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS" value="true" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: cd243cfe-514a-4705-a8d1-aa56422de8d4-->


And from the messages in  Event Viewer I am getting it might be something with Authorization or Authentication:
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions). at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<HandleAsync>g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions). at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<HandleAsync>g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

Could you please help? I am not sure what to do or how to fix it.
Also this is my Program.cs file:
using Business_Layer.AutoMapper;
using Data_Layer.Database;
using Data_Layer.InterfacesDL;
using Data_Layer.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Configure the application to use a database for production.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleDbConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NomenclOracleDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseOracle(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

//builder.Services.AddDbContext<NomenclOracleDbContext>(options =>
//    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryAppDb"), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

// Register trading partner services and business logic layers as singletons.
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITradingPartnerServices, TradingPartnerServiceDL>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITradingPartnersLogic, TradingPartnerBusinessLogic>();

// Register AutoMapper for mapping between data layer models and business layer DTOs.
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

// This adds security enhancements by enforcing SSL in supported browsers.
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
});

// This adds security enhancements by enforcing SSL in supported browsers.
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // Use the group name from appsettings.json for the admin role policy
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminGroup", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole(builder.Configuration["AllowedGroups:Admin"]));
});

// Add Razor Pages to the service container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Apply the "RequireAdminGroup" policy to all Razor Pages
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "RequireAdminGroup");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure error handling and HSTS middleware.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); // Use a custom error page in production.
    app.UseHsts(); // Enable HSTS in production to enhance security.
}

// Middleware configuration for serving static files, handling HTTPS redirection, and setting up routing.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseSession();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Map a default route to redirect to the Trading Partner Form page.
app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Redirect("/TPForm"));

// Map Razor Pages in the application.
app.MapRazorPages();

// Start the application.
app.Run();

I tried to see if there are issues in the web.config(no progress), I changed the 'AddAuthentication' a few different ways, and I tried to check if there are issues with the IIS Manager configurations.

See this link for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
